# title with trademark symbol with Angular title service

Tags: angular, title

I need to set page title with trademark sysmbols (TM) in angular 11 application dynamically.
if I use `AppName&trade;` in html title tage, it is working fine but if I use Angular provided title service in component constructor, it is not working. showing the complete text as it is '`AppName&trade;`'. I want to show 'AppName™' as title.

Below is the reference for Angular code -

```
titleService.setTitle('AppName&trade;');
```

https://angular.io/guide/set-document-title

can anyone let me know how we can use ™ `&trade;` using Angular title service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Unicode characters to get the Trademark symbol ™ `\u2122`.
I added the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qalen-wpei8v) for the same for your reference.

Refer to this [link](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm) to find Unicode for other special symbols

Comment: Thanks @Rajat. it is working as expected.

Comment: if it helped request you to accept the answer so that it could be useful for others as well.